# Vue filters not resolved when file outside of project root

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-loader, vue-cli, vue-filter

If I import a filters file that lives outside of the project directory (registering them with `import Vue; Vue.filter(...)` I get the error `Failed to resolve filter`.

If I save a copy of the file inside the app's folder and import it from there, the filter will work, but... I don't want a copy of the same file. The app/build is created with the Webpack Vue-CLI. Not sure how to get around this. I know it's not the structure expected by the webpack build/dev, but I'm confused why the location of the file would affect how the code functions.

#### \utils\filters.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.filter('useless', value => {
  return value;
});
```

#### \apps\my-app\my-component.vue (built with Vue webpack CLI)

```
<script>
import './../../../utils/filters';
</script>
```

Is it possible that because the `filters.js` imports `Vue` from a different place that it's importing a different version of Vue? Or is there another way to register filters that could be used to get around this?

Comment: I get a different error where it can't resolve vue from inside filters.js (outside of the project structure, no sibling node_modules folder). What version of the cli are you using?

Comment: Hmm.. that sounds similar. what error are you getting?

Comment: i'm not sure which version..  `error: unknown option '-v'` :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that `Vue.filter()` is being called on a different instance of `Vue` when it is being included based on a different `package.json`, even if it specifies the same version. There may be a way to tell webpack a way to compile these things differently, but a better approach is to convert the filters to a [plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html), with an install script that you pass `Vue` to, so it's whichever Vue you're already using:

```
  const vueFilters = {
    install(Vue) {
      Vue.filter('useless', value => {
        return value;
      });
    }
  };

  export default vueFilters;
```